# iOS UITextView delegate in another file

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

Good afternoon!

Excuse me for my English.

I've got a problem trying to assign textView's delegate to another class.

1. I have a CommentsViewController and a ViewController in a storyBoard connected to it.
2. I've got an UITextView element on ViewController(in storyBoard) and an outlet to CommentsViewController (called newCommentTextView).
3. I've created a class CommentTextViewDelegate: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate.
4. In CommentsViewController's viewDidLoad I've done this

   ```
   newCommentTextView.delegate = CommentTextViewDelegate()
   ```
5. I've added and textViewDidChange, and textViewDidEndEditing, and _:shouldChangeTextInRange:... . But none of these functions are called, when I change textView's text!

What's wrong with me? 
Thank you.

Comment: Why should you set an outlet in a controller and set the delegate in another?

Comment: what is the relationship between CommentsViewController and ViewController?

Comment: @TonyHan In storyBoard, in viewController's identity inspector I assigned class to CommentsViewController.

Comment: @AndréMuniz Because I need two different types of delegates for textViews and try to make one, that is separated from current controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delegate is a weak pointer. So you need make property of CommentTextViewDelegate class, then assign it to text view delegate as per below code. After this you will be getting notify whenever any changes occur.

```
  let textViewDelegate = CommentTextViewDelegate()
  func viewDidLoad() {
  newCommentTextView.delegate = textViewDelegate
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`newCommentTextView.delegate = CommentTextViewDelegate()` has an error.The instance of CommentTextViewDelegate has been released after viewDidLoad() is called.So CommentsViewController should own the `CommentTextViewDelegate`.

```
let textViewDelegate = CommentTextViewDelegate()
func viewDidLoad() {
   newCommentTextView.delegate = textViewDelegate
}
```